How to block specific file types and sizes from being downloaded in Chromium-based browsers using PowerShell registry updates?
I am working on a browser management system that remotely manages Chromium-based browsers (Google Chrome, Microsoft Edge, Brave, etc.) on other devices using PowerShell to push updates directly to the Windows registry
My goal is to block the download of specific file types (e.g., .exe, .mp3) and limit downloads based on file size (e.g., block downloads larger than 10 MB). I want to implement these restrictions without relying on GPO (Group Policy), so all changes will be done via registry updates.
I understand that browser settings related to security and downloads are usually controlled by policies configured in the registry, but I’m not sure how to implement this for specific file types and sizes.
I tried modifying the registry to block all downloads using this PowerShell script:
New-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\Software\Policies\Google\Chrome" -Name "DownloadRestrictions" -Value 3 -PropertyType DWORD -Force
I expected it to block only certain file types (e.g., .exe and .mp3) and limit downloads based on file size, but this policy blocks all downloads regardless of file type or size.
